# Correct location of git on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, git

On Mac OS x 10.6.6 I have **git** installed in **/usr/bin/** I wanted to update the git version however the git installer puts it in **/usr/local/git/bin/**

I realise I could rearrange to path to point to the local one first, but what I do not get is where the `/usr/bin/git` version came from.

Could it be part of an xcode install and lastly how would I delete it correctly? I have looked and looked but find nothing, and I didn't install it with ports etc. thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `pkgutil --file-info /usr/bin/git` to see if the system knows where it came from.  But my guess is something other than XCode or an Apple package (unless you just installed XCode 4; I have no idea about it) put it there and you should just remove it.

Comment: I did install xcode 4 and thats what makes me wonder as it is on the MacBook too in the same place.       `path: /usr/bin/git

pkgid: com.apple.pkg.GitLeo
pkg-version: 4.0.0.9000000000.1.1248867338
install-time: 1299573884
uid: 0
gid: 0
mode: 755
` So it looks like Apple I guess.

Comment: I too installed Xcode 4 on a new MacBook pro yesterday and now I have git 1.7.3.4 installed in `/usr/bin/` and I have git 1.7.4.1 installed by Homebrew in `/usr/local/bin/`. My best guess is that Xcode 4 installs git in `/usr/bin/`. I opened a StackOverflow question to ask if Xcode 4 installs git. http://stackoverflow.com/q/5364340/95592

Comment: @Matthew: @zcreem's `pkgutil` output leaves no doubt about it, it's part of XCode 4.

Comment: Is it really that difficult for Apple to keep everything it installs together? What's wrong with just having all of XCode in /Developer?